# Can we configure a service class with multiple DAO's..?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mybatis

I have hit this peculiar problem where I need to fetch the data from two different datasources. I am using myBatis and as per their documentation one sqlSessionFactory can refer only one datasource and since the sqlSessionFactory is injected into DAO, the idea of a DAO with multiple sources is out of the window. I was thinking to create a generic service class that would interact with mutiple DAO's.Is it possible.? If yes, how..? And if not, why not..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have hit this peculiar problem where I need to fetch the data from two different datasources.

--> As you are using two data sources, you may use/create two SessionFactory. I am not aware of myBatis. What you can do is create `BaseDao` class, extend it by all dao classes. Autowire two `SessionFactory` and `DataSource`. Create two different getter methods to get sessions from two Session factories. You can access both SessionFactories from all Dao classes.

```
public class BaseDao {
    // Declare and autowire session factory 1 -> defined in configuration
    // Declare and autowire session factory 2 -> defined in configuration

    // getter method to get session from factory 1
    // getter method to get session from factory 2
}


public UserDaoImpl extends BaseDao implements UserDao {
    // here you can directly access sessions from factory 1 & 2 using getter methods in BaseDao

}
```

Comment: Can we do something like that.. ? I mean can we autowire two SessionFactory to a single DAO.. ? And then how will I define a bean for the `BaseDAO`.. ?

Comment: I have extended SqlSessionDaoSupport in my DAOImpl. Should that be removed.?

Comment: Let me rephrase that. Do I need to extend `SqlSessionDAOSupport` as well .. ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to inject several beans which implement the same interface into your service - check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18095604/1990089), it may be what you are looking for. Simple approach would be:

```
interface DevService
{
   void add(Device d);
   String getName();
}

@Service("devServiceLocal")
class DevServiceLocalImpl implements DevService
{
   void add(Device d) {...}
   String getName() {return "local";}
}

class Controller
{
   @Autowired
   Collection<DevService> services;

   void doSomethingWithService()
   {
      // TODO: Check type somehow
      String servType = "local";
      for(DevService s: services)
      {
         if(servType.equals(s.getName())
         {
            // Call service methods
            break;
         }
      }
   }
}
```